# Create dict with non-string indexes(?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if is possible to create a dict like this:

```
{index:'value',index2:'value2'}
```

Instead:

```
{'index':'value','index2':'value2'}
```

Is this possible?

There's a way at least?
Just want to know, I've been seen this in:

```
$.ajax{
    ...
    data: {index:'value',index2:'value2'},
    ...
}
```

Indexes should be created before?
Indexes are "constants" pre-created?

If it cannot be on Python, can you tell me why?

Comment: Your second example appears to be JavaScript, which is a different language to Python. No, you can't use non-existent identifiers as keys in Python dictionaries; if you want string keys, you need the quotes.

Comment: Oh :( ..........

Comment: Not possible, but you need define index and index2 
index = 1
index2 = 2
dic = {index:'value',index2:'value2'} Instead of question, you can try at command line.

Comment: @AnupYadav It seems to be an idea.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz yes, work around. not that much useful.

Comment: @AnupYadav Yes, well I tried.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are `index` and `index2` defined or do you want the values of undefined variables as keys?

Comment: @timgeb are undefined.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Python only allows immutable (cannot be changed) data types for 'key' of a dictionary. This would include variables.

In this case, running my understanding of your requirement, this is what I get from the python shell.
[image]